# How to add listeners to listview and toggle button separately?

Tags: android, android-listview, togglebutton

I am quite new in android. I want to create a listview with a togglebutton on each item. I want to open a new activity when the Text on the list item is clicked. And change the state od the toggle button when the toggle button is clicked. 
The UI would look something like below.

### Item 1    |True

---

### Item 2    |False

---

### Item 3    |True

I know how to open a new activity when clciked on a listview. I know how to change the state of a toggle button. But i am not able to find out, how to have toggle button on the listview and the click on the listview not to effect the toggle button and the click on toggle button not to effect the listview.
Maybe both should have separate listeners. But i am not being able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people looking for an answer. [This](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/) post really helped me to achieve what was desired.

The Basic idea is to do something as below.

```
public class DontPressWithParentButton extends Button {

  public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public DontPressWithParentButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    if (pressed && getParent() instanceof View && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
  }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bummi . I understand. I dint post the solution coz its too long. But i sure will post the essentials here. cheers.